# The determinant of any $3\times 3$ matrix of rank $2$ is $0$, and generalization

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Here i want to show
The determinant of of any $3\times 3$ matrix of rank $2$ is $0$. 
Can anyone give me a hint or proof for this?

Further it is generalized to: for any $n\times n$ matrix of rank $k$, all the $(k+1)$-minors vanish.

Please give me some hint or prove of above statements. 
Thanks

Comment: rank $2$ implies only one eigen value is $0$. As determinant is the product of the eigen values then complete the proof..

Comment: @S.Panja-1729, Ah. your right. I just forgot the meaning of determinant, the product of eigenvalues.  How about the second statement? From the rank condition, the rank $k$ of $N\times N$ matrix, its determinant be zero. But how about their minors?

Comment: In general, for a matrix of order $n\times n$ if rank $k(<n)$ then the determinant is zero.

Comment: I've edited the title and question so the sentences make sense. I also changed "$k$ minors" to "$(k+1)$ minors", since without that change the claim is obviously false; I must suppose you did not mean that.

Comment: You must be clear what definition of the rank you are using. One of the definitions of rank is the size of the largest nonzero minor of the matrix, and this would make all the claims obvious. (By the way, even so for rectangular matrices; there is no reason to limit to square matrices.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rank two condition on $A$ means that the Gauss eliminations gives
$$
A\sim \left(\matrix{* & * & *\\ 0 & * & *\\ 0 & 0 & 0}\right).
$$
The Gauss eliminations does not change the determinant, therefore
$$
\det A=\det\left(\matrix{* & * & *\\ 0 & * & *\\ 0 & 0 & 0}\right)=0.
$$